# Data type for arithmetic expressions with let bindings in haskell

Tags: haskell

Data type for arithmetic expressions with let bindings in haskell

Comment: `let x = 2` isn't an expression (or at least, it's not an expression that affects any other expression). Are you looking to add an assignment *statement* to your language?

Comment: Sorry I was confused chepner, the second part of the question gives a context to what is required hopefully now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a variant of the original `Expr` type that adds variables (`V`) and let bindings (`Let`).

```
data Expr = C Float | V String
          | Let [(String, Expr)] Expr
          | Expr :+ Expr | Expr :- Expr
          | Expr :* Expr | Expr :/ Expr
```

To help write `evaluate`, you may want to start with a function that does variable substitution:

```
data Expr = C Float | V String
          | Let [(String, Expr)] Expr
          | Expr :+ Expr | Expr :- Expr
          | Expr :* Expr | Expr :/ Expr
            deriving Show

-- | @sub var value e@ replaces variables named @var@ with the value @value@
-- wherever anywhere that variable occurs in expression @e@.
sub :: String -> Expr -> Expr -> Expr

-- "let x = y in x" = y
sub v1 value (V v2) | v1 == v2 = value

-- "let x = y in z" = z
sub _ _ e@(V _) = e

-- Constants are unaffected
sub _ _ c@(C _) = c

-- For operators, apply @sub a b@ recursively to the operands.
sub a b (e1 :+ e2) = (sub a b e1) :+ (sub a b e2)
sub a b (e1 :- e2) = (sub a b e1) :- (sub a b e2)
sub a b (e1 :* e2) = (sub a b e1) :* (sub a b e2)
sub a b (e1 :/ e2) = (sub a b e1) :/ (sub a b e2)

-- The variable is shadowed by a let binding, so only substitute
-- into the bindings, and leave the body expression unmodified.
sub a b (Let bindings e) | bindingsContains a bindings =
    Let (subIntoBindings a b bindings) e

-- Apply @sub a b@ recursively to the body of the let expression.
sub a b (Let bindings body) =
    Let (subIntoBindings a b bindings) (sub a b body)

bindingsContains :: String -> [(String, Expr)] -> Bool
bindingsContains x bindings =
    Data.Maybe.isJust $ Data.List.find ((== x) . fst) bindings

subIntoBindings :: String -> Expr -> [(a, Expr)] -> [(a, Expr)]
subIntoBindings a b bindings = (fmap . fmap) (sub a b) bindings
```

Comment: Now `sub "e" (C 2) $ Let [("e", C 3), ("f", V "e")] $ V "f"` evaluates to `Let [("e",C 3.0),("f",C 2.0)] (V "f")` rather than `Let [("e", C 3), ("f", V "e")] $ V "f"` which is what I'd expect from an Haskell-style let-binding. Then again OP's question was about binding a *single* variable at a time which would not suffer from this problem. I suppose, your smart multi-let could be defined as a combinator by a simple `foldr` rather than a constructor.

Comment: @gallis Earlier revisions of the question specified no "recursive" bindings, and I believe this is what it meant.

Comment: I'm not talking about recursive bindings, but shadowing. Which leads me to notice that the current setup suffers from variable capture: `sub "e" (V "f") $ Let [("f", C 2)] $ V "e"` evaluates to `Let [("f",C 2.0)] (V "f")`. Ouch. Personally, I always get binding wrong so I tend to try to get the typechecker on my side to prevent all of these issues.

Comment: Crap, yeah, this is more complicated than I first thought. Good learning exercise :)